# Use an argument like std::vector<std::complex<double>> in boost::asio::buffer

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I am trying to create an UDP communication between two hosts using boost library, but instead of sending/receiving a string i want to send a `std::vector<std::complex<double>` structure.

To be more specific, i have a greater function that returns me a buffer of `std::vector<std::complex<double>` type. By using .front() i can see the values from the buffer. The catch is that i want to use buffer.front() as an argument to a sender function, namely "`auto sent = socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(buffer.front()), remote_endpoint, 0, err);"`

I attached a part of the code of interest if it helps:

```
void Sender(std::vector<std::complex<double>> in) {

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    udp::socket socket(io_service);
    udp::endpoint remote_endpoint = udp::endpoint(address::from_string(IPADDRESS), UDP_PORT);
    socket.open(udp::v4());

    //std::cout<<"The message is:"<< in<<std::endl;

    boost::system::error_code err;
    auto sent = socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(in), remote_endpoint, 0, err);
    socket.close();
    std::cout << "Sent Payload --- " << sent << "\n";
}


        int main()
    {.....
     .....
     .....
     for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
       std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
       Sender(buff.front());
    }
```

My problem is in the Sender argument what should i have instead of`std::vector<std::complex<double>` because is not working, i get an error of conversion, and the next question is if it is posible of doing this, i mean sending this type of data.

I also attached the error that return me if i try to compile:

```
error: could not convert ‘input.std::vector<std::complex<double> >::front()’ from ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::complex<double> > >::value_type {aka std::complex<double>}’ to ‘std::vector<std::complex<double> >’
    Sender(input.front());
```

Thank you!

Comment: What type is `input` or `buff`... from your question it's not clear, what do you wanna send, the whole vector or only an element?

Comment: The buff is a std::vector<std::complex<double>> and i want to send only an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your error message again:

> error: could not convert ‘input.std::vector<std::complex<double> >::front()’ from ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::complex<double> > >::value_type {aka std::complex<double>}’ to ‘std::vector<std::complex<double> >’
>
> Sender(input.front());

If we reword it slightly as:

> error: could not convert ‘input.std::vector<std::complex<double> >::front()’ from std::complex<double>’ to ‘std::vector<std::complex<double> >’
>
> Sender(input.front());

It becomes a bit more obvious what the problem is. `input.front()` just returns (a reference to) the first element of the vector, but `Sender`  wants the whole vector.  You want:

```
Sender(input);
```

---

Aside: I would change the argument to `Sender` to be:

```
void Sender(const std::vector<std::complex<double>>& in)
```

This way you don't need to make a copy of the vector - you just use a (constant) reference to the original vector.  If you are going to be sending this over UDP, copying the vector is probably pretty insignificant - but it's a useful habit to get into.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the problem is with the input.front(), but i noticed that if i display input.front() i see a complex value such as (a,b), where a is the real part and b the imaginary one. Therefore, i need to send over UDP these values not the address of the values

Maybe i'm not so clear. If you are knowing about uhd c++ api, there is a function like: `rx_stream->recv(&buff.front(), buff.size(), md, 3.0, enable_size_map);` in which it saves samples from an rf device and stores them in this buffer called buff. If i understand from the function it stores the samples, which by the way are complex, into the host memory, or sort of.

This happens in real time, and i want some how to transmit that &buff.front() via UDP. To respond at the questions from above, i think the samples are sent one at a time, and not the hole vector, because is in real time. Corect me if i'm wrong.

If i write: `std::cout<<&buff.front()` i get an address and if i write: `std::cout<<buff.front()` i get a value like (0.000102,0.2213322). I'm thinking that this value i need to transport over UDP.